# How to format ant design calendar use moment js

Tags: date, format, antd

I used ant design calendar and want to console log the date I selected.
When I console log the selected date without using moment js.
the result will be the date I selected. code as follows,

```
<Calendar
        fullscreen={false}
        onChange={(date) => {
          console.log(date);
        }}
      />
```

console log result as follow(select DEC 14, 15, 16)

M {$L: 'en', $u: undefined, $d: Wed Dec 14 2022 01:39:22 GMT-0500 (北美东部标准时间), $x: {…}, $y: 2022, …}
EventsPage.js:114

M {$L: 'en', $u: undefined, $d: Thu Dec 15 2022 01:39:22 GMT-0500 (北美东部标准时间), $x: {…}, $y: 2022, …}
EventsPage.js:114

M {$L: 'en', $u: undefined, $d: Fri Dec 16 2022 01:39:22 GMT-0500 (北美东部标准时间), $x: {…}, $y: 2022, …}

However, when I use moment js to change the date format, the result will be the current(today) date whatever day I selected. code as follows,

```
 <Calendar
        fullscreen={false}
        onChange={(date) => {
          console.log(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        }}
      />
```

result as follow(whatever date selected)

2022-12-26

How can I format using moment js in the right way so that console log the date I selected? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example without using `moment`

**Note**: antd v5.1.2

```js
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Calendar } from "antd";
const App = () => {

  const onChange = (value) => {
    console.log(value.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  };

  return (
    <Calendar fullscreen={false} onChange={onChange} />
  );
};
export default App;
```

Output:

`onChange` It will show the selected date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

[image: screenshot]